# thymlead Error resolving template not found

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-4

I use thymlead for the first time. I would like to have header body and footer.
I'm getting exception whetever I try.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "templates/layout", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
```

Here is my tiles configuration files :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition" template="templates/layout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="templates/header" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="templates/index" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="templates/footer" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="index" extends="base.definition">
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

This is my mvc configuration class.

```
package com.myproj.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.dialect.TilesDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring4.web.configurer.ThymeleafTilesConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring4.web.view.ThymeleafTilesView;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.myproj.spring")
@PropertySource("classpath:myproj.properties")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver result = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        result.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        result.setSuffix(".html");
        result.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        result.setOrder(1);
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafTilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        ThymeleafTilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new ThymeleafTilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "classpath:tiles/tiles-def.xml" });
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        templateEngine.addDialect(new TilesDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        viewResolver.setViewClass(ThymeleafTilesView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

and my controller

```
package com.myproj.spring.config;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class DefaultController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("index page");
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("login page");
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Here is my project structure

[image]

I'm using Spring Tools Suite and embedded Tomcat 8.
Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to put templates in src\main\resources.

Comment: hope this [setup spring and thyemleaf](https://anwaarlabs.wordpress.com/2017/02/19/thymeleaf-project-structure-day-1-hello-world/) might help as well.